# How do you add greater than filter in Apache superset?

Tags: supertest, apache-superset

I am new to Apache Superset and wanted to know if there's a way to implement "greater than" filter. For example, I have a column like this:

```
Cost
2000
2400
3000
1200
2320
1000
1800
2010
2800
```

I know that I can put a cost filter that says:

```
Cost: [2000][2400][3000]
```

And put all my filtering entries here, but what I actually want is something like this:

```
Cost: [>=2500]
```

Which will provide me output as:

```
Cost
3000
2800
```

Just wondering if there's a way to do so?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

You can write a custom sql creating groups of values for the Cost column and use that column in your Filter. Something like this

Select Cost, Case when cost >1000 and cost<2000 then '<2000' when cost >2000 and cost<3000 then '<3000' end

Comment: I see thanks! As if now there's no absolute way in filter right?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately No.

The issue is being tracked here
[Dashboard conditional filter on numbers](https://github.com/apache/incubator-superset/issues/6099)
but it has been closed.

You can comment on that thread to show interest.